# Trigger to restrict users from deleting Attachments from Notes and Attachments object in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, standard-objects

I am trying to prevent users from deleting Attachments from Notes and Attachments. Somehow my code is not working. Please help.

my Code -

```
trigger AttachmentTrigger on Attachment (before delete) {

    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        
        for(Attachment att: Trigger.Old){
            if(att.parent.Type == 'OBJECT_NAME'){
                att.addError('Attachments cannot be deleted!!');
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working?  Are you getting an error?  please [edit] your post to include important details.

Comment: I am trying to delete the attachment from the related list of an object. No error message is seen. File is getting deleted.

Comment: You need to [edit] your post to include those details.

Comment: Its well written. sfdx already gave me an idea about it. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationship fields aren't automatically populated, which is why your code isn't working. Use `getSobjectType`, instead:

```
for(Attachment att: Trigger.Old){
    if(att.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Object_Name.sObjectType) {
        att.addError('Attachments cannot be deleted!!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi again sfdx - The problem is - even if I remove that parent object criteria, its still not running. Note - I am using classic.

Comment: @PraveenBehera Are you certain you're not using Files, instead? Attachments work only in Classic, but Files works in both Lightning and Classic.

Comment: So, if I add a trigger on ContentVersion, it will work on both? Classic and Lightning?

Comment: @PraveenBehera You need two triggers; read [ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink trigger behavior in Classic and Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381623&type=1).

Comment: I will go through it. Just want to double confirm - I am clicking the del link under Notes & Attachments in classic.

Comment: @PraveenBehera So, I just tested in my org that has attachments, not files, and the trigger worked as expected. If it's not working for you, you're probably using Files.

Comment: Thanks, may be I should use Files for triggers and see if it works.. Will mark this answer soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145273/discussion-between-praveen-behera-and-sfdcfox).